# Run jupyter notebook through command line and log outputs to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a notebook on command line in AWS SageMaker but I am not able to log outputs to a file. I added `print`, `logging.info` and `sys.stdout.write` statements in hope of capturing something but to no avail.

Below is the code I am using

```
NOTEBOOK_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/mynb.ipynb"
LOG_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/logs.txt"

nohup jupyter nbconvert  --to notebook --inplace --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --execute "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" > "$LOG_FILE" &
```

On doing `cat "$LOG_FILE"` I get just a couple lines of logs and nothing after that. Output is below -

```
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | Config option `kernel_spec_manager_class` not recognized by `NbConvertApp`.
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/tata1mg.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3
```

PS:

Comment: `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute mynotebook.ipynb > logs.txt` try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the notebook to a script:
`jupyter nbconvert  --to script  "$NOTEBOOK_FILE"`

and then run the Python Script:
`python3 mynb.py > $LOG_FILE`